# Android Studio : updating score overwrite in array

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am working on SOS game currently. When you have **SOS** sequence, player score is updated. I used array to check if any **SOS** sequence exists.

When there are 2 **SOS** sequence on the board, my program count previous SOS and update the score according to number of **SOS** sequence existing on the board. For example, when player 1 made **SOS** sequence, p1 score increments to 1. When player 2 made **SOS** sequence p2 score increments to 2 not 1 (**Check Image**).

I couldn't figure out, I tried array list but I couldn't solve the problem. My program keep overwriting the scores. How can I handle this problem ?

[image: İmage of the game]

Here is my  `checkSOS` method:

```
public void checkSOS() {
    String[] btString;
    btString = new String[49];
    Button[] buttons;
    buttons = new Button[49];
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {            
            String buttonID = "btn" + (i+1);
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
            buttons[i] = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
            btString[i] = buttons[i].getText().toString();

    }

    int p1sc = 0;
    int p2sc = 0;
    TextView playersc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p1score);
    TextView player2sc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p2score);

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
           if (i <= 46) {
             if(btString[i].contains("S") 
             && btString[i + 1].contains("O") 
             && btString[i + 2].contains("S") 
             && i != 5 && i != 6 && i != 12 
             && i != 13 && i != 19 && i != 20
             && i != 26 && i != 27 && i != 33
             && i != 34 && i != 40 && i != 41) {
                   if (playerTurn == 1) {
                          p1sc += 1;
                          playersc.setText("" + p1sc);                              
                          Toast.makeText(this,""+a,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                   else  {
                         p2sc += 1;
                         player2sc.setText("" + p2sc);

                  }

            }// if statement for horizontal
     } //For loop
 }
```

Comment: Please format your code before paste into the question. This is impossible to read

Comment: @FisNaN It is formatted now sir. Thanks for your help.